# Main-Class: Manifest - how to define an entry point with arguments

Tags: java, class, arguments, parameter-passing, manifest

I have a jar file with predefined entry point in its manifest file. And it can successfully be executed.

```
hadoop jar hadoop-test-1.0.2.jar -write -nrFiles 1 -fileSize 10
TestDFSIO.0.0.4
12/06/11 21:35:09 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: nrFiles = 1
12/06/11 21:35:09 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: fileSize (MB) = 10
12/06/11 21:35:09 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: bufferSize = 1000000
12/06/11 21:35:09 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: creating control file: 10 mega bytes, 1 files
12/06/11 21:35:09 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: created control files for: 1 files
12/06/11 21:35:10 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/06/11 21:35:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201206110904_0029
12/06/11 21:35:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/06/11 21:35:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
12/06/11 21:35:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
...
```

Now my concern is how to execute the jar without the options.
I mean I just want to invoke:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-test-1.0.2.jar
```

I need to somehow define the arguments like `"-write -nrFiles 1 -fileSize 10"` inside the jar file. But how?

How can I define it in the manifest file? I know that I can generate a class of my own which then initiates the test class with these parameters. But is there any other workaround?

Surprisingly: Defined a class which calls the required class with the args.

Execution try:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-test-1.0.2.jar 
RunJar jarFile [mainClass] args...
```

With the name of the class as arg, it works!

```
hadoop jar hadoop-test-1.0.2.jar Start
TestDFSIO.0.0.4
12/06/12 01:05:11 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: nrFiles = 10
12/06/12 01:05:11 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: fileSize (MB) = 1000
12/06/12 01:05:11 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: bufferSize = 1000000
12/06/12 01:05:11 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: creating control file: 1000 mega bytes, 10 files
12/06/12 01:05:11 INFO fs.TestDFSIO: created control files for: 10 files
12/06/12 01:05:11 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 10
12/06/12 01:05:12 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201206110904_0033
...
```

Content of my Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 20.1-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: Start

Name: org/apache/hadoop
Implementation-Title: Hadoop
Implementation-Version: 1.0.2
Implementation-Vendor: Apache
```

The content of the Start.java:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.TestDFSIO;
public class Start {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
                String [] myargs  = {"-write","-nrFiles","10","-fileSize","1000"};

                TestDFSIO.main(myargs);

        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why am I not able to execute Start using the jar file without args to execute the original class TestDFIO? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You can either create a new `main` method or get the arguments from somewhere else, for example, a config file, environment variables, etc.

You could also just write a wrapping shell script that does that part.

Without knowing *why* you need to do this it's more difficult to provide actionable ideas.

Comment: I use a tool to execute my jar file which does NOT give any opportunity of providing arguments. It should be a jar file which can be executed with jar myjarfile.jar. That is it, no more complications. I can only execute jar files. It sounds weird. The only way is to create another jar with another class calling the mentioned class with the arguments?

Comment: @Bob What tool (a) only allows you to run jars, and (b) has no provisions for command line args? Get new tools. I don't see what your options are, although you could exec it.

Comment: This solution works, but I'd agree with @DaveNewton, the tool you are using seems more of a hindrance than a help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. Instead you could try creating another main class with no arguments that calls the original main with the arguments that you need.

Comment: Did I reach the limit of the different possibilities of jar configuration? :-)

Comment: I think your solution type is called wrapper.

Comment: :) I just noticed that your question already had this solution. Anyway, I think it's the only solution.